# Replying to discussion board using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am using an issue list in conjunction with a discussion board in office 365.

I want to post changes to the issue list metadata to the discussion board as a reply to the subject **( this was automatically created when a new issue was created)** I can't seem to get the entry to register as a reply any ideas??